# useEffect() without a cleanup function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

it says that : "Each time that our component renders, our effect is called, adding another event listener. With just a few clicks and re-renders, we have attached a lot of event listeners to the DOM! We need to clean up after ourselves!".

so for every click the count goes from 1 to 3 to 7 instead of incrementing by 1. I don't understand how does so many event listeners got attached and how is this effecting the total count?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Counter() {
  const [clickCount, setClickCount] = useState(0);

  const increment = () => {
    setClickCount(prev => prev + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', increment);

  })

  return (
      <h1>Document Clicks: {clickCount}</h1>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please post the rest of the code.

Comment: _Every_ time the component renders you are adding _another_ eventListener to the document in your effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using an array of dependencies, every change will trigger your `useEffect` to run again.

So every re-render, every changing state will cause you to create another `eventListener`.

Let's talk about variant `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // invoking on every re-render
})
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  // invoking on component did mount (once)
}, [])
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  // invoking on component did mount and with every change on counter
}, [counter])
```

Also, you need to remove your `eventLinstener` on the component unmount:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', increment);

    return () => document.removeEventListener('mousedown', increment);

  }, [])
```

##### Optional

As mentioned with Samathingamajig in the answers, you can use an optimized way to define your `increment` function with `useCallback`.

With the current implementation, your `increment` method will be re-defined every time (with every change and re-render) but using `useCallback` it will be redefined only when the `useCallback`'s array of dependencies got changes.

```
import React, {useEffect, useCallback} from 'react';

// rest of the codes ...

  const increment = useCallback(() => {
    setClickCount(prevState => prevState + 1);
  }, [setClickCount]);
```

Comment: you have to return a function from the `useEffect` as a cleanup. You might have forgotten the `return` keyword before the function.

Comment: @decpk oh sorry, I missed the return keyword, thanks for your attention bro.

Comment: @nima this might be a silly question. what does these multiple event listeners look like after every re-render? i mean how does they work? is it like for clicking once same event listener is getting called twice or more depending on the time it was re-rendered?

Comment: Yes, when you set multiple event listeners for an `event`, the callback function will invoke multiple times. if there are 10 same event listeners, so your callback function will invoke 10 times. @Hussam

Answer (score 2):

You're adding a listener *to the document itself*, so you need to remove it when component is unmounted.

And you need to add an empty dependency array to not add a new listener on each rerender

And you either need to wrap `increment` in a `useCallback` or use a different increment function in the `useEffect`:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Counter() {
  const [clickCount, setClickCount] = useState(0);

  const increment = useCallback(() => {
    setClickCount(prev => prev + 1);
  }, [setClickCount]);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', increment);

    return () => document.removeEventListener('mousedown', increment);
  }, [])

  return (
      <h1>Document Clicks: {clickCount}</h1>
  );
}
```